# Monday to Sunday Range dates from a start date to till date in a table

Tags: php, date-range

[Please click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7qKL.jpg)I need to get Monday to Sunday Range dates from a start date to till date in a table 1st table row (tr), I am attaching the image i need like this in php

I need to get Monday to Sunday Range dates from a start date to till date in a table  1st table row (tr) , I am attaching the image i need like this in php

Here is my code

`<?php

```
$begin = new DateTime('2023-01-01');
$end = new DateTime('2023-06-01');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($daterange as $date)
foreach ($daterange as $datee){
$monday = date('w', strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d")));
$sunday = date('w', strtotime($datee->format("Y-m-d")));
if ($monday == 1 || $sunday == 0) {
   
echo "<tr>". $date->format("Y-m-d") ." To <br>". $datee->format("Y-m-d") ; } }     
?>`
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <?php

$begin = new DateTime('2023-01-01');
$end = new DateTime('2023-06-01');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($daterange as $date)
foreach ($daterange as $datee){
    $monday = date('w', strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d")));
    $sunday = date('w', strtotime($datee->format("Y-m-d")));
    if ($monday == 1 || $sunday == 0) {
       
        echo "<tr>". $date->format("Y-m-d") ." To <br>". $datee->format("Y-m-d") ;
    } 
}



?>

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have attached my code.